# Running a code with JUnit Test Cases

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I have checked out a code from CVS and need to make changes to it. The code has 2 folders

1. Java
2. Test

The later has JUnit test cases. I'm not very familiar with JUnit but as far as my understanding is, the classes are duplicated in JUnit as class names. That's why I get the error in the test folder.

```
Class "xxxxx" already exists
```

I'm not sure how do I run this project without removing the folder test. Is there a way I can make eclipse ignore the JUnit test cases for now?

Comment: It's customary to add `Test` to the ends of the class names.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the properties of the Eclipse project, open `Java Build Path / Source` and remove folder `Test`. Eclipse will then ignore the sources in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Test and normal java classes are merged together during build time, your error happens because the test classes have the exact same name as the normal classes. You should rename your test cases with some kind of prefix like `Test` to prevent them conflicting.

Doing things to work around the problem will only conflict later when you are changing the build platform, maybe your current build platform accepts it, but your future platform/editor may not, and then you have the real problems.